# Finding Closed Form Representation of A Sum of Trigonometric Functions

Tags: trigonometry, summation, closed-form

Is there a closed form representation of the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^x \cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{k}\right)$$ where $n$ and $x$ are integers? If not possible, is there a representation that uses special functions?

Comment: You can get delimiters like parentheses to adapt to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: What is $x$ in the upper limit?

Comment: @joriki Thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: @saulspatz What do you mean?

Comment: Is $x$ an integer too?  Are there any restrictions on the value?  Can $x$ be $>n$ for example?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, $x$ is a positive, non-zero integer, and it can be any number.

Comment: Maybe developping the cosinus like a power series and interchanging summation to "make appear" generalized harmonic numbers ? :)

Comment: @Kermatoni Yes, but that would use infinite series.